# Тестирование UI без запуска теста на реальном устройстве

Tags: android, android-testing

Есть ли какой-то способ тестировать отдельные `View` компоненты без запуска UI теста?

Например могу ли я проверить кейсы вроде таких:

- проверить смену состояния `View`. Например что при вызове методе `onClick()` вызывается смена состояния `View` (цвет меняется или видимость).
- проверить, что если я к примеру в `RecyclerView.Adapter` отдаю список, то он заполняется и я могу к примеру чекнуть какой-то элемент и проверить его валидность относительно передаваемого списка.
- или что при вызове какого-то метода запускается анимация.

Меня не интересует в данном случае рендеринг, только факт выполнения нужных мне методов с нужными мне параметрами.

Какие для этого используются инструменты, подходы? Что насчет Robolectric? Я о нем слышал не оч хорошие отзывы, может ли он выполнить мои требования? И есть ли какие-то альтернативы?

Comment: Я не пользовался, но вроде есть Kaspresso от ребят из Касперский.

Comment: Это же надстройка на Espresso. Она так же запускает тесты на реальном устройстве